# opendaylight: what is the purpose of InstructionKey?

Tags: opendaylight

I am programming an SDN application using opendaylight. I see that an InstructionKey is required to create an instruction but I don't know where it is used. Any idea what it's use is?

I am always setting it to new InstructionKey(0) but I am not sure if this is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InstructionKey` is not necessary. This is part of code I have created :

```
Instruction applyActionsInstruction = new InstructionBuilder()
        .setOrder(0).setInstruction(new ApplyActionsCaseBuilder()
                .setApplyActions(applyActions)
                .build())
        .build();

instructions.add(applyActionsInstruction);

Instructions allInstructions = new InstructionsBuilder()
        .setInstruction(instructions)
        .build();
```

and it works fine, the Instruction is created even without the key specified.

Comment: I am not sure why InstructionKey exists in the first place.

Comment: @LostInTheFrequencyDomain it is used as an identifier of the Instruction.

Comment: I figured, but which API uses this key?

Comment: @LostInTheFrequencyDomain what do you mean?

Comment: It is used for identifying the instruction but under what circumstances does one need to identify the instruction uniquely? After I create the instruction with an instruction key, is there some other API that USES the Instruction key?

Comment: I guess there could be a case when you need to associate an Instruction with a switch let's say, e.g. a HashMap of switch and Instruction... or any case where you want to know where you put an Instruction...